# Differential Equation with velocity as unknown

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble with the following exercise.
We are considering the following equation:

$m\frac{dv}{dt}=gm-Kv^2$

I need to solve the above equation knowing that $v(0)=32; m=128;g=10;K=5$

We have: $128\frac{dv}{dt}=1280-5v^2$

$\frac{dv}{dt}=10-\frac{5}{128}v^2$

$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{-5}{128}(v^2-256)$

$\frac{dv}{v^2-256}=\frac{-5}{128}dt$

I don't know how to continue.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use **partial fractions** on the left. We have
$$\frac{1}{v^2-256}=\frac{1}{32}\left(\frac{1}{v-16}-\frac{1}{v+16}\right).$$

Comment: When you integrate, you will get something of shape $\ln(v-16)-\ln(v+16)=kt +C$. Use the initial condition to find $C$. Then exponentiate. You get $\frac{v-16}{v+16}$ equal to an exponential. Multiply by $v+16$. You get a linear equation for $v$. Solve.

Comment: When is dv/dt the largest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7462/discussion-between-user43758-and-andre-nicolas)

Comment: Can someone just explain when dv/dt is the largest ?

Comment: The velocity is $32$ at time $0$, and is decreasing initially, and indeed always. So the velocity is largest at time $0$. I will delete most of my earlier comments, since the system gets upset with long comment strings.

Comment: It is very awkward to try to answer a question in any detail in comments. The maximum number of words is very small, and the editing facilities are not good. If you have a new question, it should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Andre

$$\int \frac{dv}{v^2-256} = \frac{1}{32} \int dv \left ( \frac{1}{v-16} - \frac{1}{v+16} \right ) = \frac{1}{32} \ln{\left ( \frac{v-16}{v+16} \right ) }+ C$$